# NSAlert's icon not displayed when using default value

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, nsalert

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsalert/1531688-icon) doing:

```
let alert = NSAlert() 
alert.icon = nil
alert.runModally()
```

should render application's icon. But I get placeholder instead.

[image]

Comment: Is every size of your `AppIcon` file filled?

Comment: Yes it is, also: `NSImage(named: "AppIcon")` is not nil

Comment: @zuziaka , what do you mean "place holder instead"

Comment: Why do you even need the second line?

Comment: instead of `alert.icon = nil`, Try `alert.icon = NSImage(named: "imageName.png")`. Make sure you copy png file to resources.

Comment: I've also noticed that depending on when you added your appIcon you may have to "Clean Build Folder" for the icon to show up

Answer (score 2):

Was just having this same problem. Initially I had only a 256@1x icon and got no icon in the alert. Once I added a 128@1x icon to the AppIcon resource however, the NSAlert displayed it properly.

And no, you don't need to explicitly set the icon to nil.

Comment: Do the icon files need to be named like that? i.e. "<name>128@1x.png"? Mine are currently like "<name>128x128@1x.png" but I'm getting the placeholder in my alerts...

Answer (score 0):

You can tried some apple built-in icons such as:

```
alert.icon = NSImage (named: NSImage.cautionName)
```

Full list of apple icons is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/name